# React native multiple button select

Tags: android, iphone, react-native

Hi I want simple a button select and deselect when I have lots of buttons in one page like toggle select but no other button will effect.

My code like below:

```
constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
               activeState: [false, false, false]
         };
         this.buttonPressed = this.buttonPressed.bind(this);
}
buttonPressed(index) {
        // I want to update array value true and false.
}


<TouchableOpacity 
       style={this.state.activeClasses[0] ? styles.rateButton : 
       styles.rateButtonActive} 
       onPress={() => this.addActiveClass(0)}>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity 
       style={this.state.activeClasses[1] ? styles.rateButton :         
       styles.rateButtonActive} 
       onPress={() => this.addActiveClass(1)}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You can suggest me a different process or method by which I can make this.

Comment: what's the purpose of addActiveClass() function?

Comment: typed mistakenly
onPress={() => buttonPressed(1)}

Comment: this.state.activeClasses = this.state.activeState ?

Comment: this.state.activeState. -- yes sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but i'll give it a try:

```
buttonPressed(index) {
        const tmpState = this.state.activeState.map((val, tmpIndex) => {
            if (tmpIndex === index) {
                return !val;
            }
            return val; 
        });
        this.setState({ activeState: tmpState });
}
```

Comment: This is nice and very nice . Fully perfect ... Thank you. Thank you Very much.

Comment: done done , I don't have 15 reputation point so can't vote . Thank you.